# How to load and use font icons?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, icons

I am using `Rails 4.0.2` with `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]` and standard (build-in) rails server and need some help to load and use the following font-icons in my application - http://fontello.com/.

I have downloaded the font files and put them in `/vendor/assets/fonts/` folder. Then in `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/shared/fonts.css` file I have added the code below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    src: url('fonts/fontello.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fontello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/fontello.svg#icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It seems everything is getting loaded correctly because there are not any errors in the browser console.

Then, using the `HTML` below I am trying to get some icons:

```
<div>
  <span data-icon="0xe800">test</span>
  <span data-icon="icon-emo-happy">test</span>
  <a href="##url##">0xe809</a>
</div>
```

but now icons arae shown - just text (I am not sure this is the correct way to load them).

In the documentation is said that:

> Usually, `apache` already has necessary settings, but `nginx` and
>   other webservers should be tuned. Here is list of mime types for our
>   file extentions:
>
> - `application/vnd.ms-fontobject` - eot
> - `application/x-font-woff` - woff
> - `application/x-font-ttf` - ttf
> - `image/svg+xml` - svg

So, in `/config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file I have try this:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", :eot
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/x-font-woff", :woff
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/x-font-tt", :ttf
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/image/svg+xml", :svg
```

and this:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.eot'] = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.woff'] = 'application/x-font-woff'
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.ttf'] = 'application/x-font-ttf'
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'
```

with server restart but nothing has changed.

Has anyone have experience in doing this and could assist me?

Comment: If this is really the path you are showing us, you are targeting the `shared/fonts` folder and there is no such folder there. So are you sure that the fonts are loaded ?

Comment: @Drip By default yes, I have created it and put the font files there. Do you think their place is not there :?

Comment: No I'm a little confused since your font are in `assets/fonts/` but you are trying to go to `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/shared/fonts`, that's why I'm asking if your font are loading properly.

Comment: The second path `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/shared/fonts.css` is the path to a separate `CSS` file which is loading the font files. In the application css file, this `font.css` file is required then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by font files not properly loaded. If you are using `css` file to declare your font class, you need to follow the steps below:

1. In your `aplication.rb` file add the following line:

   ```
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'vendor','assets', 'fonts')
   ```

   In the above case, the font files are in `app/vendor/assets/fonts` folder.
2. When declaring the font class use `assets` + `font name` reference in the URL like this:

   > ```
   > @font-face {
   >     font-family: 'fontello'; 
   >     src: url('/assets/fontello.eot');
   >     src: url('/assets/fontello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   >     url('/assets/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
   >     url('/assets/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
   >     url('/assets/fontello.svg#icons') format('svg');
   >     font-weight: normal;
   >     font-style: normal;
   > }
   > ```
3. In my case I needed to additionally `require` the `css` file holding font class declaration. In my `application.css` file, I have added the line below:

   > *= require shared/fonts.css

   Note: In my case the `font.css` file is in `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/shared/` folder.